# Display error when resizing window using glut in Linux

Tags: c, opengl, glut

I tried to write a simple glut program, but I found display error when resizing window(as the picture shows). I use Arch Linux with kde.
How can i fix it?

Before resize:

[image]

After resize:

[image]

```
#include <GL/glut.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
void myinit(void)
{
  glClearColor(1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0);
  glColor3f(1.0, 0.0, 0.0);
  glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
  glLoadIdentity();
  gluOrtho2D(0.0, 500.0, 0.0, 500.0);
  glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
}
void display( void )
{
  typedef GLfloat point2[2];
  point2 vertices[3]={{0.0,0.0},{250.0,500.0},{500.0,0.0}};
  int i, j, k;
  int rand();
  point2 p ={75.0,50.0};
  glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
  for( k=0; k<5000; k++)
  {
    j=rand()%3;
    p[0] = (p[0]+vertices[j][0])/2.0; 
    p[1] = (p[1]+vertices[j][1])/2.0;
    glBegin(GL_POINTS);
           glVertex2fv(p); 
    glEnd();
  }
  glFlush();
  printf ("display invokved....\n");
} 
void main(int argc, char** argv)
{
  glutInit(&argc,argv);
  glutInitDisplayMode (GLUT_SINGLE | GLUT_RGB);
  glutInitWindowSize(500,500); 
  glutInitWindowPosition(0,0); 
  glutCreateWindow("Sierpinski Gasket"); 
  glutDisplayFunc(display); 
  myinit();
  glutMainLoop();
}
```

Comment: try calling `glViewport()` with the current window width and height as parameters prior to drawing every frame.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Switching to double-buffering (`GLUT_DOUBLE` & `glutSwapBuffers()`) fixes it on my system:

```
#include <GL/glut.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
void display( void )
{
  typedef GLfloat point2[2];
  point2 vertices[3]={{0.0,0.0},{250.0,500.0},{500.0,0.0}};
  int i, j, k;
  int rand();
  point2 p ={75.0,50.0};

  glClearColor(1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0);
  glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

  glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
  glLoadIdentity();
  gluOrtho2D(0.0, 500.0, 0.0, 500.0);

  glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
  glLoadIdentity();

  glBegin(GL_POINTS);
  glColor3f(1.0, 0.0, 0.0);
  for( k=0; k<5000; k++)
  {
    j=rand()%3;
    p[0] = (p[0]+vertices[j][0])/2.0; 
    p[1] = (p[1]+vertices[j][1])/2.0;
    glVertex2fv(p); 
  }
  glEnd();
  glutSwapBuffers();
} 
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
  glutInit(&argc,argv);
  glutInitDisplayMode (GLUT_DOUBLE | GLUT_RGB);
  glutInitWindowSize(500,500); 
  glutInitWindowPosition(0,0); 
  glutCreateWindow("Sierpinski Gasket"); 
  glutDisplayFunc(display); 
  glutMainLoop();
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks，it works!
May I sak why it will have a problum using GLUT_SINGLE ?

Comment: @haokunli: Sadly I don't have a good explanation about why `GLUT_SINGLE` isn't working properly :(  I *was* able to reproduce the funky not-resizing behavior on my Linux machine running MATE, both with and without desktop composition enabled.

Comment: I see. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

You need to capture the resize event. In glut, you must register a callback using the function [glutReshapeFunc](https://www.opengl.org/resources/libraries/glut/spec3/node48.html). In this function you can change the projection parameters and the viewport.

Below is a small change in your program, showing how you can do this:

```
(...)
void reshape(int width, int height)
{
   glViewport(0, 0, width, height);
   glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
   glLoadIdentity();
   gluOrtho2D(0.0, width, 0.0, height);
   glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
}
(...)
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
(...)
   glutDisplayFunc(display); 
   glutReshapeFunc(reshape);  /* <--- */
   myinit();
(...)
}
```

Comment: Sorry,it doesn't work. The area which can not display correctly still can't show. But Since you expand Screen coordinates , the points won't change position when resizing window.  Still thanks.